# Can I retrieve a single character from 'sed'?

Tags: linux, sed

With the sed command, is it possible to do internal string commands? in this case the actual lines are:

```
s/9G /9F6 09999F7 09999F8 09999F9 09999G /g
s/0G /0F6 09999F7 09999F8 09999F9 09999G /g
```

The number can be set using [09] but I didn't know if I could retrieve it from, say, & and use it before the F6 in something like the following:

```
s/[09]G /(&:0:1)F6 09999F7 09999F8 09999F9 09999G /g
```

This actual code does not work, by the way.

Comment: Please add the sample string and expected output into the question. I *guess* you want `sed -E 's/([0-9]+)G /\1F6 09999F7 09999F8 09999F9 09999G /g'`, but guessing games are not encouraged on SO.

Comment: Without adding sample of input and output it is very difficult to understand question completely, please do add so.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear.

Comment: In fact I want [09[ and not [0-9] - only 0 and 9 are valid. So, if "9G" were put in, "9F6 09999F7 09999F8 09999F9 09999G " would come out.

Comment: This is absolutely basic sed, take a glance at the man page or any tutorial or just about any online script.

Comment: For someone who speaks fluent Barnett, it probably is. I don't...

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a so called *sub expression* in the form of `\(SUB_PATTERN\)`:

```
sed 's/\([09]\)G /\1F6 09999F7 09999F8 09999F9 09999G /g' file
```

From `man sed`:

> `s/regexp/replacement/`
>                 Attempt  to  match  regexp against the pattern space.  If successful, replace that portion matched with replacement.
>                 The replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched, **and
>                 the special escapes \1 through \9 to refer to the corresponding matching sub-expressions in the regexp.**

Comment: Now that looks promising - I'll look into it. Thanks!